# IE11 CSS - navigation div moves when hovering certain links

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When i hover over the nav links "dienstleistungen etc." in IE11, the navigation div moves down to the bottom with a huge margin.

I've tried: - Remove `position: relative` from all boostrap col's in boostrap.min.css.

Same problem. Any ideas?

IE8 Works and any other Browser.

Here is the html:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 hidden-xs">
                <a href="index.html">
                    <img src="img/logo.jpg" align="middle" id="logo-lg" alt="Logo Lemag Treuhand">
                </a>
                <ul class="listMenuItem">
                    <li class="listMenuChild">
                        <a href="content/services.html" class="listMenuChild--title">Dienstleistungen</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="listMenuChild">
                        <a href="content/about.html" class="listMenuChild--title">Über uns</a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="listMenuChild">
                        <a href="content/publications.html" class="listMenuChild--title">Publikationen </a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="listMenuChild">
                        <a href="content/tools.html" class="listMenuChild--title">Hilfsmittel </a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="listMenuChild">
                        <a href="content/contact.html" class="listMenuChild--title">Kontakt / Lageplan </a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
```

CSS

```
/**
------------------
NAV
------------------
**/

.listMenuChild--title {
    font-size: 1.638em;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.listMenuChild--subtitle {
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-right: -2px;
}

.sub-nav {
    margin-left: -7%;
}

.sub-nav li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    margin-top: 1%;
}

.listMenuChild {
    list-style-image: url("../img/bg_li.png");
    margin-top: 5%;
}

.listMenuChild--title:hover {
    list-style-image: url("../img/bg_li_h.png");
}

.listMenuChild:hover {
    list-style-image: url("../img/bg_li_h.png");
}

.active-bullet {
    list-style-image: url("../img/bg_li_h.png");
}

.actives {
    color: black;
}

.listMenuItem {
    margin-top: 18%;
    margin-left: 5%;
}
```

If you need the source code:

You find it [Here](http://patrickhofer.ch/lemag)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Ok, thanks i update the question

Comment: try using `ems` instead of `percentages` for the margin-top. And make sure you zero out your padding on your `ul` tag for `.listMenuItem` CSS rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a `padding: 0px` to listMenuItem. It seams that this fixes the issue even if it is not clear why. Maybe it is triggering the hasLayout property for IE browsers.

Comment: You are welcome. Moreover as far as I can see it happens the same with IE 10 as well but not IE9 and edge